# next.js 14 authentication for creating user and log in with next -auth with fireabse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next-auth, next.js14

i having problem with next auth the next -auth is not interacting with user creation  for session and jwt and callbacks and adapter it should directly store without writing   explicitly stored data, just see in **StuReg.ts**

**components/auth/StuRegForm.tsx** student register form

```
"use client"
import * as z from "zod";
import {CardWapper} from "./Card-Wapper";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"
import {zodResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {RegisterSchema} from "@/schemas";
import {Input} from "@/components/ui/input";
import {Button} from "@/components/ui/button";
import {useState, useTransition} from "react";
import{
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { FormError } from "@/components/form-error";
import { FormSuccuss } from "../form-succuss";
import { StuReg } from "@/actions/StuReg";

export const StuRegForm=()=>{
    const [error,setError]=useState<string | undefined>("");
    const [success,setSuccess]=useState<string | undefined>("");
    const [ispending, startTransition]=useTransition();
    const form=useForm<z.infer<typeof RegisterSchema>>({
        resolver:zodResolver(RegisterSchema),
        defaultValues:{
            name:"",
            email:"",
            password:"",
            confirmPassword:""
        },
    })
    const onSubmit=(values: z.infer<typeof RegisterSchema>)=>{
        setError("");
        setSuccess("");
        startTransition(()=>{
            StuReg(values)
            .then((data)=>{
                setError(data.error);
                setSuccess(data.success)
            })
        })

    }
    return(
        <>
        <CardWapper
        headerLabel="Creat an account"
        backButtonLabel="Return to your profile"
        backButtonHref="/auth/admin/profile"
        >
            <Form {...form}>
<form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
className="space-y-6"
>
    <div className="space-y-4">
    <FormField
control={form.control}
name="name"
render={({field})=>(
    <FormItem>
        <FormLabel className="after:content-['*'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500 block text-sm font-medium ">User Name</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
            <Input
            {...field}
            disabled={ispending}
            placeholder="john deo"
            className=" placeholder-slate-400"
            />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage/>
    </FormItem>
)}
/>
<FormField
control={form.control}
name="email"
render={({field})=>(
    <FormItem>
        <FormLabel className="after:content-['*'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500 block text-sm font-medium ">Email</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
            <Input
            {...field}
            disabled={ispending}
            placeholder="john.doe@example.com"
            type="email"
            />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage/>
    </FormItem>
)}
/>
<FormField
control={form.control}
name="password"
render={({field})=>(
    <FormItem>
        <FormLabel className="after:content-['*'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500 block text-sm font-medium ">Password</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
            <Input
            {...field}
            disabled={ispending}
            placeholder="******"
            type="password"
            />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage/>
    </FormItem>
    
)}
/>
<FormField
control={form.control}
name="confirmPassword"
render={({field})=>(
    <FormItem>
        <FormLabel className="after:content-['*'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500 block text-sm font-medium ">Confirm Password</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
            <Input
            {...field}
            disabled={ispending}
            placeholder="******"
            type="password"
            />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage/>
    </FormItem>
    
)}
/>
   <FormSuccuss message={success}/>
   <FormError message={error}/>
    </div>
    <Button type="submit"
    disabled={ispending}
    className="w-full text-black bg-orange-600 rounded-2xl font-semibold hover:bg-black hover:text-white hover:font-extrabold
    ">
Registor
    </Button>
</form>
            </Form>
        </CardWapper>
            </>
    )
}
```

**action/StuReg.ts file** in this user is created and stored in database ,but data must store all the user information someone try to fix this

```
"use server";
import { RegisterSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { adminDb, adminAuth } from "@/firebase/admin";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const StuReg = async (values: any) => {
  try {
    // Validate user data
    const validatedFields = RegisterSchema.parse(values);
    const { email, password, name} = validatedFields;
    const hashedPassword=await bcrypt.hash(password,10);
    const user = await adminAuth.createUser({
      email,
      password,
      displayName: name,
    });
    console.log(user);
  
    await adminDb.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      name,
      email,
      hashedPassword
    });
    
    return { success: "Account created successfully!" };
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      // Handle specific errors (e.g., email already exists)
        return { error: "User already exists" };
      } else {
        return { error: "An unknown error occurred" };
      }
  }
};
```

**auth.ts** in this i having problem with next auth the next -auth is not interacting with StuReg.ts for session and jwt and callbacks and adapter it should directly store without writing   await

```
adminDb.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
name,
email,
hashedPassword
});
```

in StuReg.ts file

// auth.ts

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@auth/firebase-adapter";
import { adminDb, adminAuth } from "@/firebase/admin";
import { StuReg } from "./actions/StuReg";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "Student-reg",
      name: "Student-register",
      authorize: async (credentials: any) => {
        try {
          const { success, error } = await StuReg(credentials); // Call StuReg function
          if (error) {
            throw new Error(error); // Re-throw error for NextAuth handling
          }
          return null; // NextAuth handles successful registration automatically
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error creating user:", error);
          throw error; // Re-throw error for user-facing feedback
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        if (token.sub) {
          session.user.id = token.sub;
          const firebaseToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(token.sub);
          session.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
        }
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.sub = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter(adminDb),
} satisfies  NextAuthOptions;
```